# Cassandra terminates with OutOfMemory (OOM) error

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

We have a 3-node cassandra cluster on AWS. These nodes are running cassandra 1.2.2 and have 8GB memory. We didn't change any of the default heap or GC settings. So each node is allocating 1.8GB of heap space. The rows are wide; each row stores around 260,000 columns. We are reading the data using Astyanax. If our application tries to read 80,000 columns each from 10 or more rows at the same time, some of the nodes run out of heap space and terminate with OOM error. Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.duplicate(HeapByteBuffer.java:107)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.getBytes(AbstractCompositeType.java:50)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.getWithShortLength(AbstractCompositeType.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.split(AbstractCompositeType.java:126)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.ColumnCounter$GroupByPrefix.count(ColumnCounter.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:164)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:136)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:84)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:294)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1363)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1220)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1132)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.getRow(Table.java:355)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:70)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1052)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1578)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

ERROR 02:14:05,351 Exception in thread Thread[Thrift:6,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:269)
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:764)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$1.toString(Murmur3Partitioner.java:171)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.describeRing(StorageService.java:1068)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.describe_ring(CassandraServer.java:1192)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$describe_ring.getResult(Cassandra.java:3766)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$describe_ring.getResult(Cassandra.java:3754)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) ERROR 02:14:05,350 Exception in thread Thread[ACCEPT-/10.0.0.170,5,main] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService$SocketThread.run(MessagingService.java:893) Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:211)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.accept(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:99)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService$SocketThread.run(MessagingService.java:882)
```

The data in each column is less than 50 bytes. After adding all the column overheads (column name + metadata), it should not be more than 100 bytes. So reading 80,000 columns from 10 rows each means that we are reading 80,000 * 10 * 100 = 80 MB of data. It is large, but not large enough to fill up the 1.8 GB heap. So I wonder why the heap is getting full. If the data request is to big to fill in a reasonable amount of time, I would expect Cassandra to return a TimeOutException instead of terminating.

One easy solution is to increase the heap size, but that will only mask the problem. Reading 80MB of data should not make a 1.8 GB heap full.

Is there some other Cassandra setting that I can tweak to prevent the OOM exception?

Comment: can you share the output of `nodetool -h localhost info`?

Comment: unfortunately, I won't have access to that cluster for the next few days, so cannot share the output of nodetool. I remember it showing heap space 80-90% used before Cassandra terminating with OOM exception.

Comment: Are you reading data while the write is happening in parallel? I've had a similar issue which was resolved by changing the default heap size of 1GB to 3GB.

Comment: No, there is no write operation in progress when I read the data. I am sure that increasing the heap space may help. but I am trying to understand why reading 80MB of data is making a 1.8GB heap full.

Answer (score 0):

> No, there is no write operation in progress when I read the data. I am
>   sure that increasing the heap space may help. but I am trying to
>   understand why reading 80MB of data is making a 1.8GB heap full.

Cassandra uses Heap and OfHeap chaching. 
First loading of 80MB userdata may result in 200-400 MB of Java Heap usage. (which vm? 64 bit?)
Secondly this memory is added to memory allready used for caches. It seemes that cassandra does not frees that caches  to serve your private query. Could make sence for overal throughput.

Did you meanwhile solved your problem by increasing MaxHeap?

Comment: I solved the problem by changing our application logic. It seems reading that amount of data is not recommended in Cassandra.